# Row from Database Cant be Display

Tags: android, database, sqlite, row

For many times, i have encountered another problem and need your help.
Im trying to get an id data from an activity and pass it to another activity, and it works. The problem is there is no error but my data from a certain id, i passed to the second activity wont show.
Here is my first activity :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
 {
    // Intent newI = new Intent(this,PDetail.class); 
     Intent newI = new Intent (Create.this, PDetail.class);
     newI.putExtra("value", arg3);
     startActivity (newI);
    // db.getList(arg3);

 }});
```

and here is my second activity :

```
 public void get() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    long count = bundle.getLong("value");
    TextView XView;
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    XView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    //XView.setText("Number: " + count);
    db.open();
    Cursor z = db.getList(count);
    z.moveToFirst(); 
    String a = z.getString(z.getColumnIndex("product"));
    XView.setText(a);
    db.close();

}
```

I've got no error but it just force closed.... Any clue ???

This is the db.getList

```
public Cursor getList(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
Cursor mCursor =
        db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
        KEY_PRODUCT,KEY_BRAND, KEY_PLACE, KEY_DATE, KEY_PRICE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
        }
        //---updates a contact---
        public boolean updateList(long rowId, String product, String brand, String place, String date, String price)
        {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_PRODUCT, product);
        args.put(KEY_BRAND, brand);
        args.put(KEY_PLACE, place);
        args.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        args.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }

}
```

Logcat show nothing useful i think...

```
07-31 15:26:26.049: W/dalvikvm(20436): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.first/com.test.first.PDetail}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at com.test.first.PDetail.get(PDetail.java:32)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at com.test.first.PDetail.onCreate(PDetail.java:18)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-31 15:26:26.049: E/AndroidRuntime(20436):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you show the logcat output, and also the db.getList() method details pls?

Comment: I already include the db.getList and the logcat above.....

Comment: Well, looks like a "CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException" is being thrown. And the fact that you have a boolean updateList method inside your getList method looks plain weird! But that could be formatting. What happens when you add some System.outs and also z.getCount() in your void get() method (immediately after the cursor is called)?

Comment: Wow..... After i erase the boolean updateList method it works! Thank for your enlightment haha... Without you i'll be stuck here forever T T thank you very much

Comment: Good stuff, glad it was helpful.